# Can we load CSV data from S3 to Redshift and RDS using same COPY command?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, psycopg2

I'm working on a class that processes CSV files into **Redshift** and also **Postgres DB**.

For copying data into Redshift, I've created a function - `process_files` that takes a **processingID**, searches the files that contain pattern like `redshift{processingID}-*.csv` in the local directory and upload and copy the **CSV** files from **S3** to **Redshift** using **COPY** command as mentioned in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-tables-from-s3.html.
like

```
copy customer 
from 's3://mybucket/mydata' 
access_key_id '<access-key-id>'
secret_access_key '<secret-access-key';
```

I'm using **Psycopg2** to connect to Redshift.

But I also need to load the data that is present in S3 to another Postgres DB not the Redshift.
The only difference is the pattern for the new Postgres DB, the pattern of files will be like
`prediction{processingID}`-*.csv. Here also I'm using **Psycopg2** to connect to new Postgres DB.

Can I use the same **COPY** command that I used for copying from S3 to Redshift for copying from S3 to the new Postgres DB?

Can I execute the same COPY command on the new Postgres DB connection and just change the file and table names for loading data? Will it work?

Comment: You are talking about using `copy customer 
from 's3://mybucket/mydata' 
access_key_id '<access-key-id>'
secret_access_key '<secret-access-key';` in PostgreSQL right?

Comment: yes. into PostgresQL

Comment: If it is about running that in PostgreSQL most likely not, [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) in PostgreSQL only seams to be able to acces the standard file system.. -> *"COPY moves data between PostgreSQL tables and standard file-system files."*

Comment: Seams i also spoke to soon [Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL Now Supports Data Import from Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/amazon-rds-postgresql-supports-data-import-from-amazon-s3/) ... Amazon seams to updated PostgreSQL source code or make a extension so that it is possible..

Comment: ok. But we are on Postgres 10.5

Comment: PostgreSQL 10.5 should support Foreign data wrappers -> https://github.com/umitanuki/s3_fdw .. You also might find other options -> [foreign-data wrapper for Amazon S3](https://www.google.com/search?q=foreign-data+wrapper+for+Amazon+S3)

Comment: ... also a option which requires no C++  , is using "untrusted" [PL/Perl - Perl Procedural Language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/plperl.html) or [PL/Python - Python Procedural Language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/plpython.html) to make internet requests to download the data.. As i did see the `python` usage under your account..